# Integrated webcam not connecting to Vmware

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, webcam, vmware-workstation, vmware-tools

I am using Windows 10 on host machine and using VMware workstation
**Version**

> VMware® Workstation 16 Pro
> version 16.1.2 build-17966106

I am running windows 8.1 as Guest window on VMware. I have succesfully updated my Guest os(Win 8.1) and installed important updates as well as I installed the Vmware tools succesfully.
When I tries to connect the webcam to Vmware by choosing *"Connect(disconnect from Host)"*, then sometimes it connects succesfully and I could able to use my webcam in VMware but sometimes It gives the error **The connection for the USB device "Microdia integrated webcam" was unsuccesfull**. Could anyone help me through this ?
My laptop specifications :
Dell vostro 15 3500
Ram 8gb
intel i3 11th gen

Answer (score 1):

I found a type of hack solution for this problem.
When you start the guest machine on VM and a small window will automatically opens like this ->

[image]

You need to click **ok** and instantly try to open Camera app on your main or host machine, and you will see that the camera app is not able to detect camera as it is now connected to host machine in VM. This would magically works everytime for me now.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try opening your windows camera, and then run VmWare, click on top left corner, there would be Player->Removable Devices->Select the camera listed, Now you can see the camera will be stopped in your Windows machine and in ubuntu, you can see its connected.
Type lsusb (list usb) and ensure that your camera device name is listed

sami@ubuntu:~/Desk$ lsusb

```
    Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:5539 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. VMware Virtual USB Hub
    Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0e0f:0008 VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual USB Mouse
    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

sami@ubuntu:~/Desk$ getfacl /dev/video*

```
    getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
    # file: dev/video0
    # owner: root
    # group: video
    user::rw-
    user:sami:rw-
    group::rw-
    mask::rw-
    other::---
    
    # file: dev/video1
    # owner: root
    # group: video
    user::rw-
    user:sami:rw-
    group::rw-
    mask::rw-
    other::---
```